# Can not resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I have the issues while setting the layout, images, etc using "R.". The below is the code which gives this error.

But the same code works fine if I choose "compile with:" as "API 19". I want my code to run on my mobile which is 2.3.3.

I have searched on google I found that there were many people had this issue. But no solutions work for me

```
package com.example.testfor23;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The below is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testfor231"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testfor231.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I choose the "compileSdkVersion 19" then it works perfectly fine.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
    }
```

Comment: fix errors i resource files and clean and build

Comment: I've had this problem before, and other than saying its a massive pain in the ass, there's not a lot more I can do if you've followed all the current answers. If worst comes to worst, try removing XML files until the error goes away...

Comment: Please also show the code for res/layouts/activity_main.xml.

Comment: The activity XML is

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Answer (score 0):

There are some resources in your project that is not compatible with 2.3.3. Fix them and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
import com.example.testfor23.R;
```

in order to fix the R errors in your Java file. If you still receive errors, then one of your XML files contains an error and you will have to find out what the errors are. Cleaning the project might help as well. Also note that you will need to set the target correctly in `project.properties`. In your case, it should be:

```
target=android-19
```

Generally, supporting older versions of Android is problematic because they don't contain many of the methods, classes and features the new ones do. This is especially noticeable for versions lower than API 10.

You can use [Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) if you absolutely must support these legacy versions.

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net), only 1.3% of devices currently run a version older than API10 (Gingerbread 2.3.3). Therefore I strongly recommend you set:

```
android:minSdkVersion="10"
```

because the added benefits of supporting those devices far outweigh the problems it causes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that occur because you might have errors in your xml, and it can be sintax error, resources that are not compatible try not having duplicates in the res-directory. Also import the R from your project, sometimes that error occurs because you havent imported the (in this case)

```
import com.example.testfor23.R;
```

Because if you don't import it, you're refering to the resource from the platform.

Comment: I dont have any other XML files. I just created new project thru android studio. It just give that error.

I could not even add "import com.example.testfor23.R;" and it gives the same error.

Comment: import the R from your project, so you can access the resource from your project, in this case ( i assume ) import com.example.testfor231.R;

Comment: @user3319315 that is false, as you are having the following line in your code: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki i think the problem comes from activity_main?

Comment: That's quite possible, but we'll need the op to post that code before we can tell..

Comment: @user3319315 can you post your code from activity_main? because if it works for api 19 then maybe you're using a widget/component that's not compatible with old versio of androids.

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: The activity main is

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: Your xml has some ; Erase those ";" and it will work

Comment: Luis is correct. Not sure if it will fix your problem but it's certainly part of the cause.